# How can we create a transparent Fragment Layout with Recycler view inside the Layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-blur-effect

[image]I have two fragment for my current application, In `FragmentA` I have a search view in Toolbar and on clicking on the search view , I have to show another fragment,`FragmentB` on top of `fragmentA`  using my framelayout,with transparent view so that the contents in `FragmentA` can be seen as blurred. The newly opened fragment with transparent background has to show some content in the recycler view . How  can we achieve the transparency and the recycler view inside the layout.

Layout code:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dot_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:elevation="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

  
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/palate_survey_bg"
    app:ignore="NamespaceTypo"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/Advance_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/filter_search_bar_bg_lyt"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        app:queryHint="Search">

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar >
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/search_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
```

Comment: I couldn't even understand what you were trying to do. Maybe a visual representation of what you want to achieve would be better.

Comment: @Noah- I have added bit more details.

Comment: @Noah- Any Updates on this?

Comment: I don't see a reason why you would need another Fragment B to display a RecyclerView. You could have used an Activity, and then inside the Activity, you have a toolbar and a FrameLayout which would then be replaced dynamically by another fragment. The RecyclerView can then be shown inside that Fragment. So one fragment should do. Or is there a specific reason ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the detailed image you provided. Fragment B is a child fragment of
Fragment A. So if you want to show Fragment B when a click event is emitted from the SearchView, you should use Fragment A's `FragmentManager`. Normally, every fragment has a FragmentManager that can house other fragment views and layouts. To retrieve Fragment A's FragmentManager use this code:

Inside Fragment A:

```
  Advance_search.setOnClicklistener( v -> {

            getChildFragmentManager()
                  .beginTransaction()
                  .replace(R.id.search_container, new FragmentB())
                  .commit();

}
```

And then inside Fragment B's onViewCreated() method, you can now inflate the RecyclerView you want into Fragment B's view hierachy.

If you want Fragment B to be transparent, set

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Or you can just remove `windowBackground` entirely.

And set `android:backgroud="@android:color/transparent"` on Fragment B or just remove it if you have set `windowBackround` to transparent.

Comment: @Noah- got it. it is working as expected.

Comment: Glad I could be of help